# Git Unable to create .lock file on WINDOWS,Because branch name contains '>'

Tags: git

```
Branch api>18 wasn't deleted
        cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/api>18': Unable to create 'C:/Users/Roxas/Documents/StudioProjects/ProjectName/.git/refs/heads/api>18.lock': Invalid argument
        Error deleting branch 'api>18'
```

I can't rename or delete this branch, please help.

Comment: Try `git branch -D 'api>18'`.

Comment: You might want to raise this as a bug on the git for windows github project. Linux will let you create a branch with a > or | character but these are invalid in filenames on windows and git creates files in the .git folder to represent these branches. Possibly git for windows needs to do some escaping scheme on filenames used in this manner.